# Locust task execution just once

Tags: locust

I often work with the Python Locust framework for conducting load and performance tests. Additionally, I have also developed smoke tests using this framework. To optimize test execution time and reduce unnecessary performance load, I implemented a sequential task execution approach, which involved terminating the instance at the end to stop the test.

However, I am now considering if there is a more efficient way to implement this behavior for smoke and regression tests. If not, I am planning to create a feature request as a merge request for Locust as part of my bachelor exam. I thought to implement wrapper to setup a execution once per instance and once in total.

To avoid redundant work, I would greatly appreciate your opinion on this matter.

1. I implemented a sequential task execution approach, which involved terminating the instance at the end to stop the test.
2. Had a quick look in the internet

Answer (score 1):

[The `on_test_start` event](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#test-start-and-test-stop) should do what you want. Locust will run functions tagged with that listener each time a test is started. The linked doc page also has a an example of how to choose whether your code runs on a master or worker (in the `init` example but it can be applied anywhere). Something like this:

```
from locust import events
from locust.runners import MasterRunner

@events.test_start.add_listener
def my_on_test_start(environment, **kwargs):
    print("A new test is starting")
    if isinstance(environment.runner, MasterRunner):
        print("I'm on master node")
    else:
        print("I'm on a worker or standalone node")
```

Running your function on the master would have it run once per test. Running it on a worker would be once per worker per test.